# Traefik + Docker. www.domain.tld works, domain.tld not

Tags: docker, traefik

I've been trying to figure out the problem for two days now, but nothing comes to my mind. I have a VPS with Docker and Traefik and four domains with A record pointing to server's IP.

It seems that two out of four domains, when written as domain.tld result in connection error. When written as www.domain.tld everything seems to be working ok.

As for the two other domains they work both with and without 'www'.

Any clues what should I focus on? I'm not utterly fluent with server administration, so please excuse me if the question is trivial ;)

Comment: Your A record is set for the www 'subdomain' or just the root domain?

Comment: Both, with all four domains I have two A records

Comment: Maby take a look at https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/572#issuecomment-382270057 and test with a uncached browser instance